# Regular Expression For A Number of UpperCase Characters

Tags: regex, windows, windows-shell

there is a windows program that supports Regular Expression (or Dos Expression) for search files.

> (MythicSoft's FileLocator Pro)

it supports wildcards such as * ?
i want to find only 4 characters file names with jpg format
how can i write a phrase for that?
this phrase (????.jpg) finds all lower and upper cases.(i put it's mode to dos expression)
also this phrase ([A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z].jpg) Does not work!(i put it's mode to regular expression)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Online documentation](http://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorpro/help/) shows that FileLocator Pro uses Perl compatible regular expressions, in which case, this should work:

```
^([A-Z]{4}\.jpg)$
```

The parentheses make the whole thing a capture group. If you don't need the capture group, just remove the parentheses.

**Edit:**

Make sure that the case sensitive option is on for regular expressions. Go to the [online documentation](http://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorpro/help/index.html?advanced_criteria.htm) and search for `regular expression case sensitive`. It appears to be explained there. It says 'To make the content search case sensitive click the 'Aa' buttons'

Comment: really thanks for help / but still does not work -> http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html i do n't know what is the problem!

Comment: Are you sure the `jpg` is lower case? You might want to post some sample files names taken directly from the file system just to verify some real input.

Comment: yes, ([A-Z]{4}\.jpg) finds many jpg files more than 4 characters and ^([A-Z]{4}\.jpg)$ finds all lower and upper cases...

Comment: i edit my prev comment | i think there is something wrong about their software!

Comment: I don't know anything about FileLocator, but there must be a setting somewhere that makes your regular expressions case sensitive. Make sure that's on.

Comment: would you please install this software and help me about this problem.would be really really appreciate for that.i was working some hours on it...